# How to move from a right semigroup action to a left semigroup action?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup and $X$ any set.

Define a left action of $S$ on $X$ to be a map $\sigma: S \times X \rightarrow X$ with the property that $(st)x = s(tx)$, where we define $gx = \sigma(g,x)$ for all $g \in G$, $x \in X$.

Similarly, a right action of $S$ on $X$ is a map $\tau: X \times S \rightarrow X$ with the property $x(st) = (xs)t$, where $xg = \tau(x,g)$ for all $g \in G$, $x \in X$.

Is there a natural bijection between left and right actions of $S$? Does a left action induce in some natural way a right action?

Basically, if I have proven something for every left action of a particular semigroup, is there a shortcut to prove it for every right action as well?

Comment: Just to be clear, why is the definition of right(left) action as above well-defined? Thanks

Comment: @BabakS.:  What exactly would it mean for it to be not well-defined?

Comment: @TaraB: I was confused about **any** in "..$X$ any set" above. It is more clear by your explanation. In fact, I didn't see this concept in Howie.

Comment: @BabakS.:  Ah, I see.  'Any' is quite a tricky word, which people should be a bit more careful with.  The usage here is completely fine though.

Comment: @spin:  What would be an example of 'something' in your final sentence?  As you can see, it might somewhat depend on the 'something'.

Comment: @TaraB: See my comment in your answer

Comment: Ah, right, I thought it was very possible this was the sort of thing you meant, but because you talked about 'a particular semigroup' I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Right actions and left actions of a semigroup can be significantly different.
(I was about to give the same example as Boris.)

It's actually very common for the left action of a semigroup on itself to be different from the right action.  This is why we have the concept of left and right Cayley graphs for semigroups.

What you *do* get is that a left action of a semigroup $S$ induces a right action of the 'opposite semigroup' of $S$, which I'll denote $S^{\operatorname{opp}}$.  This is the semigroup with the same underlying set as $S$, but with multiplication reversed, so that in $S^{\operatorname{opp}}$, for any $s,t\in S$ we have $st = t\circ s$, where $\circ$ is the binary operation of $S$.

In general a semigroup is not necessarily isomorphic to its opposite semigroup, but it is what is called *anti-isomorphic*.  An anti-isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism $\phi: S\rightarrow T$ such that $\phi(xy) = \phi(y)\phi(x)$ for all $x,y\in S$. 
Note that the reason you never hear of anti-isomorphisms in group theory is that anti-isomorphic groups are isomorphic.  If $G$ and $H$ are groups and $\phi: G\to H$ is an anti-isomorphism, then $\psi: G\to H$ given by $x\mapsto [\phi(x)]^{-1}$ is an isomorphism.

If you want to prove a result about actions of some class of semigroups, then if the class is closed under anti-isomorphism (which many natural classes of semigroups are), it will suffice to only prove the result for left actions.

Comment: Thanks, $S^{\operatorname{opp}}$ was just what I needed. There was this theorem in a book that concerns the continuity of a left action for a semigroup with a topology, so with $S^{\operatorname{opp}}$ I was able to prove its analogue for right actions.

Comment: Ah, great!  Yes, for general results like that $S^{\operatorname{opp}}$ is exactly what you need.  Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 3):

Left and right actions of semigroups (unlike groups!) can be arranged quite differently. Let $S$ be a semigroups of left zeros (i.e. with identity $ab=a$). Consider its actions on itself by multiplication (i.e. $X=S$). Then for the right action  $X$ consists of  fixed points, but for left action every $a\in S$ maps all $X$ in the single point $a$.

Comment: I was just typing up the same example! =]

Comment: Oh yes, which means +1, because obviously I thought it was a good idea.

Comment: @Tara B: "I was just typing up the same example!" - Of course, this is the first thing that comes to mind. Concerning your answer, it is worth to note (for OP) that anti-isomorphic groups are isomorphic.

Comment: Ah yes, I was going to put that in, and then I either forgot or wanted to keep it short.  But you're probably right that I should mention it.