# Is there a standard name for this semigroup?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, semigroups

Given a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) $X,$ we can form a new semigroup $Y$ by asserting that:

- the carrier of $Y$ is the set $X^2$, and
- the law of composition in $Y$ is given by $(a,b)(a',b')=(aa',b'b).$

Finally, define that the left-action of an element of $Y$ on an element of $X$ satisfies $$(a,b)x=axb.$$

Under these definitions, it is easy to see that, for all $y,y' \in Y$ and all $x \in X$ we have $$(yy')x=y(y'x).$$

Is there a standard name for this construction? And where can I learn more about it?

Comment: $Y = X \times X^{op}$. A left action of $X^{op}$ is the same as a right action of $X$. In rings, these are just called bimodules (this is the regular bimodule).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Y$ is the direct product of $X$ with its opposite, the semigroup denoted by $X^{\text{op}}$: $$Y = X \times X^{\text{op}}$$

If $X$ is a semigroup, we can define a  semigroup $X^{\text{op}}$ such that $X, X^{\text{op}}$ are opposite semigroups: As Jack notes in the comments, a left action of $X^{\text{op}}$ is the same as a right action of $X$.

For some nicely compiled notes from Pete L. Clark, see [Introduction to semigroups and monoids](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/semigroup.pdf). You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350337/how-to-move-from-a-right-semigroup-action-to-a-left-semigroup-action) helpful, too.

Comment: Even a nice reference with link +1 :-1

Comment: You think Pete L. Clark's notes are nicely compiled?  I think they're mostly a collection of trivialities with actual mathematical content promised but not delivered.  I'll admit the guy has some good lecture notes, but he should show some restraint.  (I am in fact mostly serious.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, you're funny. :)